# keep the checkbox checked browsing through the paging (Using PagedList asp.net mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of orders in a gridview with customer html which has paging using PagedList asp.net mvc. I have a checkbox for each order in the list. When I use "Check all" to check all orders it should keep the checkbox checked when I go to page 2-3-4. But I lose the checked status when I move to next page. Can anyone help please?

JavaScript code :

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $('#selectAll').click(
            function () {
                $('#TabOrdre td input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('#TabOrdre td input:checkbox').each(function () {
                        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), list) === -1)
                            list.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    getAll = true;                    
                }
                else {

                    list = [];
                    getAll = false;
                }
            }
        );
```

View code :

```
<section class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading m-b-none">Liste des ordres</header>
    <div class="row wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-12 space20">
            <div class="doc-buttons">
                <a class="btn btn-s-md btn-warning ajout-container"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Ajouter un ordre </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="20">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="-1">
                    </th>

                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        EDA
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        <span class="th-sort">
                            Immediat
                        </span>
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        JNA
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Heure début
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Heure fin
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Puissance
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        RP
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        RS
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Caractérisation
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Commentaire
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Source
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Date de création
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap">
                        Refus
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space:nowrap" class="th-sortable" data-toggle="class">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ORD_ID)
                        <tr>
                            <td>                                                            
                                <input type="checkbox" value="@item.ORD_ID" id="chk_@item.ORD_ID" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_NOM)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @(Convert.ToBoolean(item.EDA_IMMEDIAT) ? "Oui" : "Non")
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @(Convert.ToBoolean(item.EDA_JNA) ? "Oui" : "Non")

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_DEBUT != null)
                                {@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_DEBUT, "ShortDateTime")}
                            </td>
                            <td style="white-space:nowrap">

                                @if (item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_DEBUT != null)
                                {@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_DEBUT, "ShortTimeString")}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_FIN != null)
                                { @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_ORDRE_DATE_FIN, "ShortTimeString")}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_PUISSANCE)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_PUISSANCE_RP)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_PUISSANCE_RS)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Eda_Caracterisation)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.COMMENTAIRE)

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.SOURCE_NOM)

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @if (item.EDA_DATE_RECUPEREE != null)
                                { @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EDA_DATE_RECUPEREE, "ShortDateTime")}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.VAL_REFUS)
                            </td>
                            <td >
                                @if (item.MODIFIABLE == 0)
                                {
                                    <a class="btn btn-warning editor-container" data-id="@item.ORD_ID" data-toggle="modal" 
                                       ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                }
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center " colspan="16">
                            @VideResult
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-s-md btn-warning" id="Accepter">Accepter</button>
                <button class="btn btn-s-md btn-default" id="Refuser">Refuser</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-right text-center-xs">
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, Page_No => Url.Action("Liste",
                       new
                       {
                           eda = ViewBag.eda,
                           Source = ViewBag.Source
                       ,
                           datedeb = ViewBag.datedeb
                       ,
                           datefin = ViewBag.datefin
                       ,
                           refus = ViewBag.refus
                       ,
                           page = Page_No
                       }),
                       PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast
                       , new AjaxOptions()
                       {
                           HttpMethod = "GET",
                           UpdateTargetId = "TabOrdre",
                           LoadingElementId = "loader"
                       }))
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</section>
```